# How to properly rename a button name controlled within a <span> tag?

Tags: html, button, rename

#### HTML:

```
<td tabindex="5" class="buttonTD" id="BTN_TB_LeadDetailForm_QualifyLead" style='border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-image: url("//images/button1.gif");'onclick="doNamedInvoke('Submit',this)">
<span data-odtype="imgcontainer"></span>
<span data-odtype="txtcontainer">&nbsp;Mark as Completed&nbsp;</span></td>
```

Struggling how to rename the value between `<span>` tags from `Mark as Completed` to `Complete`.

The latest code I test but still doesn't work.

#### JavaScript:

```
ctr = 0;
$(".buttonTD").each(function(index) {

  if ($("span").innerHTML === "&nbsp;Mark as Completed&nbsp;") {
    (this).innerText = "Complete";
    alert("mac");                                                            
  }
  ctr++;                      
});
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: rename "Mark as Completed" to "Completed"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").each(function(index) {

    var currentVal = $(this).text();

    if (currentVal == "&nbsp;Mark as Completed&nbsp;")
    {
        $(this).text("Complete");
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks Namrehs! it doesn't work from my end, but based on your code I derived with this:

Comment: $('#BTN_TB_LeadDetailForm_QualifyLead').text("Qualify");

Comment: however, if I run it using IE debugger tool, it works and the fields are editable. But when viewing the page in normal mode, I can see that the button is renamed, BUT I can no longer able to edit any fields in the form. would you know the reason why?  apologies for multiple comments/alerts

Comment: @Marc, try to replace `.text()` with `.html()`. Because `text()` will interpret the `&nbsp;` and then your `if` statement will fail.

Comment: Thank you @azeós for your advice! i'll do that